# Getting buggy ConvexHullShape from a g3dj/g3db file although it works with wavefont (obj) in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, bullet

I recently played around with libGDX & Bullet and had trubble getting a working ConvexHullShape from a g3db file (created in Blender and converted afterwards with the fbx-converter following the [tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX)). So I loaded it into the [ConvexHullTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/bullet/ConvexHullTest.java) what didn't worked either (but renders perfectly) and looked like [this](https://youtu.be/FpVUtzVTEmw). I noticed that it did work when I use a export in wavefont of my Model.

```
assetManager = new AssetManager();
assetManager.load("firstShip.g3dj",Model.class);
assetManager.finishLoading();

final Model carModel = assets.get("model.g3dj",Model.class);
```

*loading the g3dj file into the ConvexHullTest*

```
final Model carModel = objLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("model.obj"));
```

*loading the wavefont file into the ConvexHullTest*

Where could be the problem with the g3dj file causing it to render perfectly but not being able to create a decent ConvexHullShape from it?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else getting this problem: My simple workaround is to export the model twice from Blender. One as wavefont(.obj, Y-axis Up) for the CollisionShape and one as g3db/g3dj for the actual model that gets rendered. In the end it is probably better to use one model exclusive for the Collision Shape anyway. It gives you the possibility to reduce the Verts in the ColisionShape to get more efficient collision calculation, it is just a little bit unfortunate I have to use wavefont in order to achieve it.